# Can't get store value after the value was updated using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a SearchBar component and it has a subcomponent SearchBarItem.

I passed the method `handleSelectItem()` to subcomponent to dispatch value to store and it works (I saw it from the Redux tool in Chrome).

Then, when I tried to get the value from the method `submitSearch()`, which I also passed it from the parent component, it shows:

```
Cannot read property 'area' of undefined.
```

I'm still not so familiar with React. If someone can help, it will be very appreciated. Thanks in advance.

This is parent component SearchBar:

```
class SearchBar extends Component {   
  handleSelectItem = (selectCategory, selectedItem) => {
    if (selectCategory === 'areas') {
      this.props.searchActions.setSearchArea(selectedItem);
    }
  }

  submitSearch() {
    console.log(this.props.area); // this one is undefined
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="searchBar">
        <SearchBarItem
          selectCategory="areas"
          name="地區"
          options={this.props.areaOptions}
          handleSelectItem={this.handleSelectItem}
          submitSearch={this.submitSearch}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  area: state.search.area,
  brandOptions: state.search.brandOptions,
  vehicleTypeOptions: state.search.vehicleTypeOptions,
  areaOptions: state.search.areaOptions,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  searchActions: bindActionCreators(searchActions, dispatch),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SearchBar);
```

This is subcomponent SearchBarItem:

```
export default class SearchBarItem extends Component {
  state = {
    showOptions: false,
    selectedItem: [],
  }

  handleSelectItem = (selectedItem) => this.props.handleSelectItem(this.props.selectCategory, selectedItem);

  submitSearch = () => this.props.submitSearch();

  handleClickCategory = () => {
    this.setState({ showOptions: !this.state.showOptions });
  }

  handleClickItem(option) {
    this.setState({
      selectedItem: [...this.state.selectedItem, option],
    }, () => this.handleSelectItem(this.state.selectedItem));
  }

  render() {
    const options = this.props.options.map((item, index) => (
      <div
        className={this.state.selectedItem === item ? "searchBarItem＿＿option--active" : "searchBarItem＿＿option"}
        key={index}
        onClick={() => this.handleClickItem(item)}
      >
        {item}
      </div>
    ));

    const optionBox = (
      <div className="searchBarItem＿＿box">
        <div
          className="searchBarItem＿＿option"
          onClick={() => this.handleClickItem('')}
        >
          不限{this.props.name}
        </div>
        {options}
        <div className="searchBarItem__confirm">
          <span>取消</span><span onClick={() => this.submitSearch()} >套用</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    );

    return (
      <div className="searchBarItem">
        <span onClick={() => this.handleClickCategory()} >
          {(() => {
              switch (this.state.selectedItem.length) {
                case 0: return this.props.name;
                case 1: return this.state.selectedItem[0];
                default: return `${this.state.selectedItem.length} ${this.props.name}`;
              }
            })()}
        </span>
        { this.state.selectedItem.length > 0 ? '' : <Icon icon={ICONS.DROP_DOWN} size={18} /> }
        { this.state.showOptions ? optionBox : '' }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

SearchBarItem.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  selectCategory: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  options: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string).isRequired,
  handleSelectItem: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  submitSearch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};
```

Comment: change `submitSearch() {
    console.log(this.props.area); // this one is undefined
  }` to `submitSearch = () => {
    console.log(this.props.area);
  }`

Can explain later (writing it via the phone now)

Comment: it works! thank you so much! And yes, if you can explain later will be super helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem caused by the behavior of `this` pointer in javascript.

By writing the code `submitSearch={this.submitSearch}` you are actually sending a pointer to the `submitSearch` method but losing the `this` pointer.

The method actually defers as `MyClass.prototype.myMethod`. By sending a pointer to the method `MyClass.prototype.myMethod` you are not specifying to what instance of `MyClass` it belongs to (if at all). This is not the most accurate explanation of how `this` pointer works but it's intuitive explanation, you can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work) about how `this` pointer works

You have some possible options to solve it:

*Option one (**typescript/babel transpiler only**) - define method as class variable*

```
class MyClass{
    myMethod = () => {
       console.log(this instanceof MyClass) // true
    }
}
```

this will automatically do option 2 for you

*Option two - Bind the method on the constructor*

```
class MyClass{
    constructor(){
        this.myMethod = this.myMethod.bind(this)
    }
    myMethod() {
       console.log(this instanceof MyClass) // true
    }
}
```

By the second way, you are binding the method to current this instance

Small note, you should **avoid** doing:

```
<MyComponent onSomeCallback={this.myCallback.bind(this)} />
```

[`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) returns a new method and not mutating the existing one, so each render you'll create a new method and it has performance impact on render (binding it on the constructor only once as option two, is fine)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I used binding the pointer on other places but without knowing what's that mean. Big help, thank you so much.